# IPID field unexpected increase

Tags: python, sockets, udp, raw-sockets

Intro:
I have an exercise where I need to send a file from S to D through a third party T only.
T is run on port 10000 or 11000 depending if i use UDP or TCP; i use UDP, and T's ip is given both to S and D.
T is given and all it does is echo messages it got back to the sender.
One of the fields in the header of T's echo message is called ip_id - a counter that goes up by one with each message T receives; in order to view the ip_id value i need to use raw sockets.

S/D sends a message to T and is then supposed to receive back a message. S/D needs to check that the ip and port that it got the message from matches the one it sent to (that is, if S/D sends a message to 1.1.1.1:5 it should receive a message from 1.1.1.1:5).

First I open a socket and a raw socket once

```
self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
self.raw_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
```

I then get my port by doing:

```
self.s.sendto("1", (self.remote_server, UDP_PORT))
self.myPort = self.s.getsockname()[1]
```

UDP_PORT is 10000 and is the port to send messages to.
remote_server is the ip to send messages to.

I also have the following method:

```
def send_value(self, number_of_packets):
    for i in range(0,number_of_packets):
        self.s.sendto(BOGUS_DATA, (self.remote_server, UDP_PORT))
        self.raw_socket.recvfrom(1024)
        #self.raw_socket.recv(1024)
```

And as well as this one:

```
def recieve_ip_id(self):
    try:
        sent = 0
        continueFlag = True
        while continueFlag:
            self.s.sendto(BOGUS_DATA, (self.remote_server, UDP_PORT))
            #mypacket = self.raw_socket.recv(1024)
            mypacket = self.raw_socket.recvfrom(1024)
            mypacket = mypacket[0]
            continueFlag = False
            if (256*ord(mypacket[20])+ord(mypacket[21]) != UDP_PORT):
                continueFlag = True
            if (256*ord(mypacket[22])+ord(mypacket[23]) != self.myPort):
                continueFlag = True
            sent = sent + 1
        ip_id = 256 * ord(mypacket[4]) + ord(mypacket[5])
        print "packet 20 21 " + str(256*ord(mypacket[20])+ord(mypacket[21])) + " packet 4 5 " + str(256 * ord(mypacket[4]) + ord(mypacket[5])) + " packet 22 23 " + str(256*ord(mypacket[22])+ord(mypacket[23]))
        print ip_id
        return (ip_id, 0)
    except socket.timeout:
        # dummy
        return (0, 0)
```

It works good enough in the sense that it checks correctly who it got the message from; The problem is that the ip_id wont advance as expected. after some time the programs are running they each get ip_id as if it was not shared anymore.
am i not checking something correctly, or is it something else?
Thanks.